# Successful Login AFTER Failed Login Redirects to wp-login.php Instead of Last Viewed Site Content Page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, authentication

I am using wp-login with some modifications for a project.

Originally I was using this code in the theme's functions.php to have users redirected to the main page after login and everything worked like a charm:

```
/* redirect users to front page after login */
function redirect_to_front_page() {
global $redirect_to;
if (!isset($_GET['redirect_to'])) {
$redirect_to = get_option('siteurl');
}
}
add_action('login_form', 'redirect_to_front_page');
```

Then I began testing the site and realized it would be better if people were redirected to the last page they visited.  That way if they were viewing content other than the main page and decided to log in to comment they wouldn't get booted back the main page.

I then altered the code to read like this:

```
/* redirect users to last page viewed after login */
function redirect_to_last_page() {
global $redirect_to;
if (!isset($_GET['redirect_to'])) {
$redirect_to = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
}
add_action('login_form', 'redirect_to_last_page');
```

It works perfectly except in the case of a failed login.  In that case they get sent back to wp-login with an error message, which is fine.  But when they try to log in a second time and are successful, instead of redirecting back to the site content page they came from they are being redirected back to wp-login with no explanation.

I can see it remembers the instance of wp-login without the error as the referer and that this is creating my problem.  But I don't have a good mental picture of how to make this situation conditional, nor has anything I've read made any sense in the context of my problem.

UPDATE:

I got it to work by starting a session and using the strstr() function.  This code was added at the very top of the wp-login.php file:

```
session_start();

$lpage = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(strstr($lpage, 'login.php') == false)
{
$_SESSION['referrer'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

Then I changed the code in functions.php to this:

```
/* redirect users to last page viewed after login */
function redirect_to_last_page() {
global $redirect_to;
if (!isset($_GET['redirect_to'])) {
$redirect_to = $_SESSION['referrer'];


}
}
add_action('login_form', 'redirect_to_last_page');
```

However, I would rather not be making changes to Wordpress core files.  So if anyone can suggest a way to move all this into functions.php it would be appreciated.  I tried to just add the code into functions.php instead of wp-login but it throws an error.

If someone spots a potential security problem that would also be helpful.